# $(X,\mu , \mathcal F)$ be measure space , $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be non-negative integrable function , then is $m(A):=\int_A f d\mu$ countably additive?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu , \mathcal F)$ be a measure space , $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be a non-negative  integrable function , then is it true that $m:\mathcal F \to\mathbb R$ defined as $m(A):=\int_A f  d\mu , \forall A \in \mathcal F$ is a measure ? The only part I am having difficulty with is countable additivity . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove this for mutually disjoint sequences. Let $\{A_n\}$ be a mutually disjoint sequence of measurable sets. Then, $\int_{\bigcup A_n} f d\mu = \int_X f\chi_{\bigcup A_n} d\mu =\int_X f\sum \chi_{A_n} d\mu = \sum \int_X f\chi_{A_n} d\mu = \sum \int_{A_n} f d\mu$. I used monotone convergence theorem here.